# Mod(%) is not an identifier Unix ksh

Tags: unix, ksh

I have converted one function from C language to Unix ksh script and below is the code

```
 function greg_julian
{
    typeset -i long_date=$1;
    print "$scriptname ld $long_date" 1>&2;  # Prints 20160121
    set days -9999 0 31 59 90 120 151 181 212 243 273 304 334;

    if [[ $long_date < 101 ]] then
        return 0;
    fi

    typeset -i yy=$long_date/10000;
    typeset -i mm=$long_date/100 % 100;

    ymod=$(( $yy % 4 ))
    if [[  $ymod -eq 0 && $mm -gt 2 && $yy -ne 0 ]] then
        dm=1;
    else
        dm=0;
    fi  
    echo $yy*1000 + ${days[$mm]} + $long_date % 100 + $dm;
}
```

I get an error as below. Tried removing space around %. but same error. I am Unable to figure out the error please help.

```
 greg_julian[87]: %: is not an identifier
```

Comment: You could also use something like `let result=16%5` to calculate a modulo in ksh.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use an intermediate variable:

```
#!/bin/ksh

long_date=20160121
typeset -i yy=$long_date/10000;
typeset -i yymm=$long_date/100;
typeset -i mm=$yymm%100;
printf "%04d\n" $yy
printf "%02d\n" $mm
```

Comment: perfect it works ! Thanks. had to remove the space around % too

Answer (score 0):

One way to calculate mathematical expressions in shell script is to use expr.

Can you, please, try it and make a feedback please?